# Extension of weak solution

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am reading an article from Conca, San Martin and Tucsnak in which they prove the local existence of weak solutions of the system describing the motion of an rigid body immersed in an incompressible fluid in a bounded domain. More precisily, they show that for every unitial data $u(0, \cdot) = u^0$ there exists a $T_{max}$ so that there is a weak solution on $[0,T]$ for all $T < T_{max}$. Moreover, we have an energy estimate
$$E(t) \le E(0),$$
for $E(0)$ only depending on the inital data and the shape of the domain. Now at the end of the proof, they say that as we have a weak solution provided that $T < T_{max}$, this solution can be extended to a maximal one defined on $[0,T_0)$ for some $T_0 > 0$. How do they conclude such an extension ?

Assume that $u$ is a weak solution on $[0,T]$ for $T < T_{max}$. Now taking $u(T)$ as an initial condition, it will give me a weak solution $\tilde{u}$ on $[T, \tilde{T}]$, for $\tilde{T} < \tilde{T}_{max}$, where $T_{max}$ depends on $u(T)$ and the shape of the domain. How can I construct a weak solution on $[0,\tilde T]$ ? How can I be sure that
$$v = 
\begin{cases}
u &\text{on }[0,T],\\
\tilde u & \text{on }[\tilde T, T]
\end{cases}
$$
is still a weak solution ?

I can add more detail about the equation I am dealing with but it seems to be quite a general argument.

Comment: I think you need to add more details. I am a bit confused concerning the fact that you stated the existence of a solution on a closed interval, beccause I have seen a lot of times weak solutions lying in spaces for which it does not make sense to evaluate the solution pointwise in time.

Comment: Let’s assume we are working with intervals that are open on the right... You always have a solution defined on $[0,T)$ for some $T>0$. Then, you can use Zorn’s lemma to show the existence of a maximal solution defined on $[0,T_0)$ for some $T_0$. For this, you need to use the definition of weak solution, but I think this should work in any reasonable setting. At that point, the only thing you don’t know is whether the solution can be extended to a solution over $[0,T_0]$… But honestly, I don’t even know whether this even makes sense in your setting.

Comment: Check this post to see what I mean (this is for ODEs): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73760/does-zorn-lemma-imply-the-existence-of-a-not-unique-maximal-prolongation-of-an